# Identify a code by quantity intervals in a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given the following DataFrame in pandas:

| avg_time_1 | avg_time_2 | avg_time_3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1200 | 34 | 1 |
| 90 | 45 | 3600 |
| 0 | 4 | 1 |
| 0 | 4 | 50 |
| 80 | 4 | 60 |
| 82 | 40 | 65 |

I want to get a new DataFrame from the previous one, such that it assigns the following code to each row if any of the three columns visit_time, exceeds the following values:

- CODE-1: All values are less than 5.
- CODE-2: Some value is between 5 and 100.
- CODE-3: All values are between 5 and 100.
- CODE-4: Some value is higher than 1000.

Applying the function, we will obtain the following DataFrame.

| avg_time_1 | avg_time_2 | avg_time_3 | codes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1200 | 34 | 1 | 4 |
| 90 | 45 | 3600 | 4 |
| 0 | 4 | 1 | 1 |
| 0 | 4 | 50 | 2 |
| 80 | 4 | 60 | 2 |
| 82 | 40 | 65 | 3 |

Thank you for your response in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far? You could show the code you have written in order to get useful suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `np.select`, note that you should put the higher priority condition ahead.

```py
df['codes'] = np.select(
    [df.lt(5).all(1), df.gt(1000).any(1),
     df.apply(lambda col: col.between(5, 100)).all(1),
     df.apply(lambda col: col.between(5, 100)).any(1)],
    [1, 4, 3, 2],
    default=0
)
```

```
print(df)

   avg_time_1  avg_time_2  avg_time_3  codes
0        1200          34           1      4
1          90          45        3600      4
2           0           4           1      1
3           0           4          50      2
4          80           4          60      2
5          82          40          65      3
```

Comment: Your code has problems if I have additional columns in the DataFrame, how can I fix it to apply only to the ```avg_time``` columns?

Comment: @Carola Change `df` in code to `df.filter('avg_time')`.